# Convert time hh:mm:ss to decimal values (hours or minutes)

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, charts, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a chart using a SQL database, I am using the duration column(HH:mm:ss) and the People column(Names).

But ASP does not support Time values for charts .Is there any other approach to display a TIME value like "45:34:12" to a column chart?I am trying to achieve a result like the one below.

[image]

If it is not possible ,is it possible in SQL to convert all the column that contains the "HH:mm:ss" values to a new decimal hour's column ?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP `classic`?  Please revise your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use a number instead.

Like it could be 10.84 hours or 2567.5 minutes.

This should work, but is less beautiful than the `HH:mm:ss` format.